# Formatting string in java. string->regex->format

Tags: java, string, formatting

I have function in java that takes 3 arguments:
 - String to format
 - regex code to fit in groups
 - String like "Here %s, then %s, finally %s" to fit in groups that got fitted by regex.

And here is my question. Is there a short function in java that could reformat my string like I described here? Or should I write my own method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes. You can achieve this with Formatters. Just google it or take [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2012/08/how-to-format-string-in-java-printf.html) as an initial reading.